# PHP exec error, possibly MAMP using ghostscript

Tags: php, exec, mamp, ghostscript

I have been trying to use ghostscript in PHP to convert pdf files to images (png, jpg).

I don't really care as long as they are images.  This is the code that I used.

```
exec("gs -sDEVICE=jpeg -sOutputFile=/Applications/Mamp/htdocs/cover.jpg -r144 /Applications/Mamp/htdocs/test.pdf");
```

When I enter the exact same thing, without the exec and quotes obviously, into the command line it does exactly what I want.  However, when I run the php file nothing happens.  I am using a MAMP server and the server seems to work fine, whenever I run another file with it I have no issues.  Anyone have any ideas why it might not execute right?

Comment: Have you tried entering the full location of the `gs` executable? It's probably not in PHP's path.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was trying to figure this out for hours, I asked all my friends, I have a meeting tomorrow and my boss was going to kill me if I didn't have this done.  Such a simple fix, thank you

Comment: Excellent, I'll give it a proper answer.

Answer (score 5):

The `gs` executable is likely not in PHP's path, so it is unable to run it by using `exec()`. Entering the full path to the command will allow it to be run within PHP.

To find the full path you can run `which gs` from the command line, since it is executable to you, and then copy that path into the `exec()` method.

```
> which gs
/path/to/gs
```

Update `exec()` in PHP

```
exec("/path/to/gs -sDEVICE=jpeg -sOutputFile=/Applications/Mamp/htdocs/cover.jpg -r144 /Applications/Mamp/htdocs/test.pdf");
```

Comment: Thanks for this. This is what I'm looking for